# Why is opening String class inside thor file not working?

Tags: ruby, thor

I know I can open a class like `String` and add functionality. This test script `camelize.rb` works pretty well.

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
class String
  def camelize
    self.split("_").map(&:capitalize).join
  end
end

class Test
  def test
    p "test_me".camelize
  end
end

Test.test
```

Prints `"TestMe"`

However inside a thor file this doesn't work. E.g. `test.thor`

```
p "TEST ONE"
class String
  p "TEST TWO"
  def camelize
    self.split("_").map(&:capitalize).join
  end
end

class Test < Thor
  p "TEST THREE"
  desc "camel", "A test"
  def camel
    p "test_me".camelize
  end
end
```

Installing it via `thor install test.thor`, running

```
$ thor test:camel
"TEST ONE"
"TEST TWO"
"TEST THREE"
/Users/Kassi/.thor/ba3ea78d7f807c4c13ec6b61286788b5:13:in `camel': undefined method `camelize' for "test_me":String (NoMethodError)
```

Why and how to fix it?

Comment: Sorry, that happens when you adapt the test code on the fly for SO. Changed it accordingly.

Comment: I doubt that it can be reproduced. I don't see `camelize`on line 12.

Comment: Blame on me. Again I added a line afterwards and did not adapt the output.

Comment: Please don't fabricate the result, give what you really got.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Why?

The problem is [here](https://github.com/erikhuda/thor/blob/c74e1d34ef8b3270dcaa821fc1c7b38238929a27/lib/thor/util.rb#L155):

```
Thor::Sandbox.class_eval(content, path)
```

So what it does is take your file and load it inside of an [empty module](https://github.com/erikhuda/thor/blob/c74e1d34ef8b3270dcaa821fc1c7b38238929a27/lib/thor/util.rb#L4-L5), thus namespacing it (not sure if qualifies as "sandboxing").

```
class Thor
  module Sandbox
  end
end
```

So, your attempt at reopening the `String` actually creates a new class `Thor::Sandbox::String` which no one knows about. String literals continue to create instances of `String`.

### How to fix?

Open the top-level string instead of creating a nested one.

```
class ::String
  def camelize
    self.split("_").map(&:capitalize).join
  end
end
```

### Bonus content

Thor actually already includes method for camelizing strings, [`Thor::Util.camel_case`](https://github.com/erikhuda/thor/blob/c74e1d34ef8b3270dcaa821fc1c7b38238929a27/lib/thor/util.rb#L104-L107):

```
  def camel_case(str)
    return str if str !~ /_/ && str =~ /[A-Z]+.*/
    str.split("_").map { |i| i.capitalize }.join
  end
```